# What LaTeX math markup can pandoc translate into MathML?

Tags: pandoc, mathml

I'm working with a gitit wiki because we can use LaTeX markup for mathematical formulas.  However, I am learning that I can't use such sequences as `$\mathbb R$` or `$\mathcal A$` or even `$\mathbf X$`, as they don't get translated into MathML. How can I found out what markup is actually supported?

Comment: pandoc isn't really on topic for this site, but have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104455/convert-markdown-embedded-latex-to-pdf-and-doc  which suggests there is a --mathjax rather than --mathml option which might be a better option currently

Answer (score 2):

The conversion takes place in the function `writeMathML` in the source file [`src/Text/TeXMath/Writers/MathML.hs`](https://github.com/jgm/texmath/blob/master/src/Text/TeXMath/Writers/MathML.hs) of the `texmath` module that is used by pandoc.

If you want to know precisely how this converts which element in TeX to which element in MathML, you won't get around reading the source code.  However, a quick search can tell us which kinds of tags can possibly be generated (no guarantee for completeness):

```
$ grep -o 'unode *"[^"]*"' src/Text/TeXMath/Writers/MathML.hs | sort | uniq
unode "math"
unode "menclose"
unode "mfrac"
unode "mi"
unode "mn"
unode "mo"
unode "mover"
unode "mphantom"
unode "mroot"
unode "mrow"
unode "mspace"
unode "msqrt"
unode "mstyle"
unode "msub"
unode "msubsup"
unode "msup"
unode "mtable"
unode "mtd"
unode "mtext"
unode "mtr"
unode "munder"
unode "munderover"
```